# Continuous vs. Monotone Functions

Tags: real-analysis

If $f\colon (a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then is it always possible to find a countable collection $\{J_i\}$ of sub-intervals of $(a,b)$ (which could be closed-open, open-closed, closed or open) such that

- $J_i'$s cover $(a,b)$ except countably many points;
- $f$ is monotonic on each $J_i$?

(I came to this question by considering the $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ function on $(0,1)$.)

Comment: No. The [Weierstrass nowhere differentiable function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is monotonic on no interval, e.g..

Comment: @DavidMitra I think what you wrote is acrually a full answer to the question, not just a comment. Perhaps post it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [Weierstrass nowhere differentiable function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is monotonic on no interval, e.g..

Comment: Oh! Thanks. This example is important in other parts of analysis also. Thanks for the nice solution.